# No app icon on delete screen

Tags: android, icons, mipmaps

I have good and well sized icon in:
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

Аfter developing the application, I noticed that the application icon does not appear in the "delete app" confirmation alert. I see only standard placeholder icon like this:

[image]

However, the right icon is displayed on the emulator as it should.
Problem appear only ON REAL devices. What should I check?
Notifacation icons also not appear on real devices.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the icons for all screen densities?

That is, mdpi, hdpi, xdpi, xxdpi and xxxdpi.